# get key - value from dict and remove this key

Tags: c#, dictionary

i have some code

```
muVar = 5782347242-8923423423-3423423432;
```

than i add it to dict. ex {1: 57, 2 : 82, 3 : 34, 4 : 72, 5 :42, 6 : -, ....} i try to get path of this var

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<int, string> kvp in myDict)
{
    if (kvp.Value == "-") { myDict.Remove(kvp.Key);  break; }
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp2 in dict2)
    {
        if (kvp.Value == kvp2.Value) var1 += kvp2.Key;
    }
    myDict.Remove(kvp.Key);
}
foreach (KeyValuePair<int, string> kvp in myDict)
{
    if (kvp.Value == "-") { mytDict.Remove(kvp.Key); break; }
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp2 in dict2)
    {
        if (kvp.Value == kvp2.Value) var2 += kvp2.Key;
    }
    myDict.Remove(kvp.Key);
}
```

but i have an exception "Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.";

Comment: Please take more care when formatting your posts - I'm sure your real code doesn't have the `foreach` bodies indented about 12 characters, so there's no reason why your post should either. It would also help if you'd format blocks in a more conventional manner rather than "several statements in the same line"...

Comment: It's *also* not clear what you expect the result to be. Yes, you have an exception after removing the item - which is mentioned in numerous other posts - but it's not clear what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: The problem here might be myDict.Remove(kvp.Key); line. In foreach statement you shouldn't touch your myDict. Its because still in process

Comment: i need to get 3 parts of "muVar".  first 5782347242, second 8923423423, third 3423423432. 3 parts separated by "-"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your foreach loop is using that collection so you can not modify that in between loop

try Using `ToList()`

```
    foreach (KeyValuePair<int, string> kvp in myDict.ToList())
{
    if (kvp.Value == "-") { myDict.Remove(kvp.Key);  break; }
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp2 in dict2)
    {
        if (kvp.Value == kvp2.Value) var1 += kvp2.Key;
    }
    myDict.Remove(kvp.Key);
}
foreach (KeyValuePair<int, string> kvp in myDict.ToList())
{
    if (kvp.Value == "-") { mytDict.Remove(kvp.Key); break; }
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp2 in dict2)
    {
        if (kvp.Value == kvp2.Value) var2 += kvp2.Key;
    }
    myDict.Remove(kvp.Key);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to collect all the items you want to remove from the dictionary:

```
Dictionary<int, string> removeDict = new Dictionary<int, string>();

foreach (KeyValuePair<int, string> kvp in myDict)
{
    if (kvp.Value == "-") { myDict.Remove(kvp.Key);  break; }
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp2 in dict2)
    {
        if (kvp.Value == kvp2.Value) var1 += kvp2.Key;
    }
    removeDict.Add(kvp.Key);
    //myDict.Remove(kvp.Key);
}
foreach (KeyValuePair<int, string> kvp in myDict)
{
    if (kvp.Value == "-") { mytDict.Remove(kvp.Key); break; }
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp2 in dict2)
    {
        if (kvp.Value == kvp2.Value) var2 += kvp2.Key;
    }
    removeDict.Add(kvp.Key);
    //myDict.Remove(kvp.Key);
}
```

And then remove them from the dictiponary:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<int, string> kvp in removeDict)
{
    myDict.Remove(kvp );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not allowed to remove or add something to an Collection in an `foreach` loop. But you Remove something from mydict `myDict.Remove(kvp.Key);` .

You could save the keys you want to remove in a list and remove them afterwards.